# Subplots with QuTip Bloch sphere

Tags: matplotlib, qutip, subfigure

I would like to know if is it possible to plot a figure with two subplots, in which one is a regular 2D plot and the other one a Bloch sphere.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

You need to manually create the `figure` object and add `axes` to it using matplotlib's OO interface. While making the axes that needs to have the Bloch sphere, you should set the projection to 3D. Finally, just call the `render` method on your Bloch sphere object so that the Bloch sphere gets rendered to the correct subplot

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from qutip import Bloch

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax1.plot(range(10), range(10), "o-")

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection='3d')
b1 = Bloch(fig=fig, axes=ax2)
b1.render(fig=fig, axes=ax2)
ax2.set_box_aspect([1, 1, 1]) # required for mpl > 3.1

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What is the q.Bloch()? Which library is that?

Comment: This is a library called qutip (https://qutip.org/). There should be a `import qutip as q` statement before this is called

Comment: Nice yess, I guessed so. But maybe you should edit the answer to make it clear? great job!